# Transforming tree nodes with levels to row list

Tags: mysql

I've got a little challenge here for you all, there is the data:

```
CREATE TABLE vCategoryTree (
    level1 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    level2 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    level3 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    level4 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    level5 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 44, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 45, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 46, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 48, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 49, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 50, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 51, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 52, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 53, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 54, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 55, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 56, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 57, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 58, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 59, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 60, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 62, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 63, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 64, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 65, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 66, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 67, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 68, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 69, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 70, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 10, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 25, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 26, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 11, 12, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 11, 13, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 15, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 16, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 17, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 18, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 19, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 20, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 21, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 22, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 23, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 24, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 27, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 29, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 34, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 37, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 38, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 39, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 41, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 42, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 31, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 35, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 40, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 32, 33, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 32, 36, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 6, 7, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 6, 8, NULL, NULL);
```

It is the result of various experiment at transforming an adjacency model to a modified preorder tree taversal model all in MySQL.

What i need to do here, is generate a list from these levels into a row based result tree, for example, i'm looking to get:

```
2
43
45
47
48
49
50
51
...
4
9
10
25
26
11
12
13
...
32
33
36
6
7
8
```

The ... are just a cut in the expected data so i can provide more of the example without actually pasting the whole thing i need, i'm not expecting ... to appear in there.

Hope this is enough...

And NO, i don't want to do it via PHP...

Thank you

Comment: please explain more about the output tree. i couldnt find any pattern

Comment: Unless i was mistaken in the resulting data, what i'm trying to achieve is build a result that shows me the exact order of categories as you would call a recursive function. But i think i won't be able to achieve that without a multi-level cursor and stored procedure

Comment: For example: 0, 2, 43, 44 is the first line and should be the first 4 records, then i would print, 45, 46, 47 because they are all under 43, then, nothing more to print below 43 so i go to 47 and print all children, and so on

Comment: In other words, for every child of level1=0, you want level2 and all of its descendants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's load your sample data

```
mysql> drop database if exists mathieu;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> create database mathieu;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mathieu
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE vCategoryTree (
    ->     level1 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     level2 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     level3 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     level4 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->     level5 INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 44, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 45, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 43, 46, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 48, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 49, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 50, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 51, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 52, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 53, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 54, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 55, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 56, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 57, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 58, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 59, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 47, 60, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 62, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 63, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 64, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 65, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 66, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 67, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 68, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 69, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 2, 61, 70, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 10, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 25, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 9, 26, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 11, 12, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 11, 13, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 15, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 16, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 17, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 18, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 19, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 20, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 21, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 22, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 23, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 24, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 4, 14, 27, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 29, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 34, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 37, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 38, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 39, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 41, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 28, 42, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 31, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 35, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 30, 40, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 32, 33, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 5, 32, 36, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 6, 7, NULL, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `vCategoryTree` (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`) VALUES (0, 6, 8, NULL, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from vCategoryTree;
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | level5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |      2 |     43 |     44 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     43 |     45 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     43 |     46 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     48 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     49 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     50 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     51 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     52 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     53 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     54 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     55 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     56 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     57 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     58 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     59 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     47 |     60 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     62 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     63 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     64 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     65 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     66 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     67 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     68 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     69 |   NULL |
|      0 |      2 |     61 |     70 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |      9 |     10 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |      9 |     25 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |      9 |     26 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     11 |     12 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     11 |     13 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     15 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     16 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     17 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     18 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     19 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     20 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     21 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     22 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     23 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     24 |   NULL |
|      0 |      4 |     14 |     27 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     29 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     34 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     37 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     38 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     39 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     41 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     28 |     42 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     30 |     31 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     30 |     35 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     30 |     40 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     32 |     33 |   NULL |
|      0 |      5 |     32 |     36 |   NULL |
|      0 |      6 |      7 |   NULL |   NULL |
|      0 |      6 |      8 |   NULL |   NULL |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
55 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now here the very, very ugly query you need

```
SELECT level,parent,IFNULL(child,'Leaf') child FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT level1 parent,level2 child,1 level
    FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL OR level2 IS NOT NULL UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT level2       ,level3      ,2
    FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level2 IS NOT NULL OR level3 IS NOT NULL UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT level3       ,level4      ,3
    FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level3 IS NOT NULL OR level4 IS NOT NULL UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT level4       ,level5      ,4
    FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level4 IS NOT NULL OR level5 IS NOT NULL
) A order by level,parent,IFNULL(child,999999999);
```

It will present each parent and child and the level of the parent.

Each row whose child is NULL is a leaf in the tree

Now here two stored procedures that I hope gives you basically a treelike display you are seeking

The first stored procedure creates a table called DisplayTree and puts the parent of your choice

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `DisplayTree` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`lwdba`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `DisplayTree`(given_parent INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DisplayTree;
    CREATE TABLE DisplayTree
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        DIsplayText VARCHAR(1024),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

    INSERT INTO DisplayTree (DisplayText) SELECT LPAD(given_parent,4,' ');
    CALL LoadDisplayTree(given_parent,1);

    SELECT DisplayText FROM DisplayTree;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The second stored procedure is a recursive one that populates the temp table DisplayTree

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LoadDisplayTree` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`lwdba`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `LoadDisplayTree`(given_parent INT UNSIGNED,given_level INT UNSIGNED)
TheStoredProcedure:BEGIN

    DECLARE children VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE howmanykids,ndx,ps1,ps2,next_child INT;

    SET children = '';

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO howmanykids FROM
    (
        SELECT level,parent,child FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT level1 parent,level2 child,1 level
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL OR level2 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level2       ,level3      ,2
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level2 IS NOT NULL OR level3 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level3       ,level4      ,3
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level3 IS NOT NULL OR level4 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level4       ,level5      ,4
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level4 IS NOT NULL OR level5 IS NOT NULL
        ) AA order by parent,level,IFNULL(child,999999999)
    ) A WHERE parent = given_parent AND child IS NOT NULL;

    IF howmanykids = 0 THEN
        LEAVE TheStoredProcedure;
    END IF;

    SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(child),',') INTO children FROM
    (
        SELECT level,parent,child FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT level1 parent,level2 child,1 level
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL OR level2 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level2       ,level3      ,2
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level2 IS NOT NULL OR level3 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level3       ,level4      ,3
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level3 IS NOT NULL OR level4 IS NOT NULL UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT level4       ,level5      ,4
        FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level4 IS NOT NULL OR level5 IS NOT NULL
        ) AA order by parent,level,IFNULL(child,999999999)
    ) A WHERE parent = given_parent AND child IS NOT NULL;

    SET ndx = 0;
    SET ps2 = 0;
    WHILE ndx < howmanykids DO
        SET ps1 = ps2 + 1;
        SET ps2 = ps2 + 1;
        WHILE SUBSTR(children,ps2,1) <> ',' DO
            SET ps2 = ps2 + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET next_child = SUBSTR(children,ps1,ps2 - ps1);
        INSERT INTO DisplayTree (DisplayText)
        SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(LPAD('X',(given_level * 8),'X'),LPAD(next_child,4,'X')),'X',' ');
        CALL LoadDisplayTree(next_child,given_level + 1);
        SET ndx = ndx + 1;
    END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
Give it a Try !!!
```

Let's display starting with parent_id 0 :

```
mysql> call displaytree(0);
+------------------------------+
| DisplayText                  |
+------------------------------+
|    0                         |
|            2                 |
|                   43         |
|                           44 |
|                           45 |
|                           46 |
|                   47         |
|                           48 |
|                           49 |
|                           50 |
|                           51 |
|                           52 |
|                           53 |
|                           54 |
|                           55 |
|                           56 |
|                           57 |
|                           58 |
|                           59 |
|                           60 |
|                   61         |
|                           62 |
|                           63 |
|                           64 |
|                           65 |
|                           66 |
|                           67 |
|                           68 |
|                           69 |
|                           70 |
|            4                 |
|                    9         |
|                           10 |
|                           25 |
|                           26 |
|                   11         |
|                           12 |
|                           13 |
|                   14         |
|                           15 |
|                           16 |
|                           17 |
|                           18 |
|                           19 |
|                           20 |
|                           21 |
|                           22 |
|                           23 |
|                           24 |
|                           27 |
|            5                 |
|                   28         |
|                           29 |
|                           34 |
|                           37 |
|                           38 |
|                           39 |
|                           41 |
|                           42 |
|                   30         |
|                           31 |
|                           35 |
|                           40 |
|                   32         |
|                           33 |
|                           36 |
|            6                 |
|                    7         |
|                    8         |
+------------------------------+
69 rows in set (0.20 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

mysql>
```

You do not have to start with parent_id 0. Let's try parent_id 4 :

```
mysql> call displaytree(4);
+----------------------+
| DisplayText          |
+----------------------+
|    4                 |
|            9         |
|                   10 |
|                   25 |
|                   26 |
|           11         |
|                   12 |
|                   13 |
|           14         |
|                   15 |
|                   16 |
|                   17 |
|                   18 |
|                   19 |
|                   20 |
|                   21 |
|                   22 |
|                   23 |
|                   24 |
|                   27 |
+----------------------+
20 rows in set (0.11 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql>
```

CAVEAT

Since recursion is involved, run this

```
mysql> set max_sp_recursion_depth = 64;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

before calling DisplayTree

Comment: Nope it's not the expected output, i need to be able to get the same output that i'd insert into a MPTT/Nested Set structure. Thus, Level1 #2 outputs first, then #43 because it's the level2, then 44 because it is level3  and so on. Just as you'd read a MPTT visual output, this will be used to insert the information into an MPTT table with the correct "lft" and "rgt"

Comment: I will update my answer with two stored procedures that I hope will be the solution you are looking for

Comment: Lookup my solution and see if you can get it to work with views like it did so without the user variables...

Comment: Your solution led me to create my final solution so i'll mark it as the answer. What i was trying to do is create an algorithm to transform an adjacency patern to modified preorder but this cannot be done using conventionnal non-recursive methods, so i'll do it using store procedures sadly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Interestingly, my stored procedure is an in-order traversal. I wrote a stored procedure (without recursion) that does preorder traversal in the DBA StackExchange back in October (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/877). Please look at it and see if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got my belly full of pizza and took some time off the problem and was able to get it working except for the fact that i can't create a view out of it. But it is very fast and effective:

```
CREATE VIEW vCategoryTreeExploded AS 
    SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5 FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5 FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5 FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5 FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5 FROM vCategoryTree WHERE level1 IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY `level1`,`level2`,`level3`,`level4`,`level5`
```

So with this first view i created up top my other view, i was able to duplicate all the lines in up 5 examples (retaining only rows that were not null) and reordering everything as it came before. This gave me a table that i could work with using a few variables:

```
SELECT categoryid
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN IFNULL(@level1, -1) <> level1 THEN @level1 := level1
            WHEN IFNULL(@level2, -1) <> level2 THEN @level2 := level2
            WHEN IFNULL(@level3, -1) <> level3 THEN @level3 := level3
            WHEN IFNULL(@level4, -1) <> level4 THEN @level4 := level4
            WHEN IFNULL(@level5, -1) <> level5 THEN @level5 := level5
        END AS categoryid
    FROM vCategoryTreeExploded, (SELECT @output := NULL, @level1 := NULL, @level2 := NULL, @level3 := NULL, @level4 := NULL, @level5 := NULL) AS initialization
) AS subdata
WHERE categoryid IS NOT NULL
```

Sadly, i cannot transform this output into a view because of the user variables or the sub selects, but since it will be a one time use to generate a list of NestedSet insert, i'm going to be all right.

I hope someone can improve on that and make it "VIEWable" if possible but i'd be really surprised if it was even possible :P

Thank you all for your implication...